# Haskell custom data type, instance Num, and redundancy

Tags: haskell, types, instance

I'm developing a small set of weightlifting utilities in Haskell as a learning exercise. I've defined a data type `Weight` such that:

```
data Weight = Wt Float Unit 
              deriving (Show, Eq)

data Unit   = Lb | Kg 
              deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Num Weight where
  Wt x Lb + Wt y Lb = Wt (x + y) Lb
  Wt x Lb * Wt y Lb = Wt (x * y) Lb
  negate (Wt x Lb)  = Wt (negate x) Lb
  abs    (Wt x Lb)  = Wt (abs x) Lb
  signum (Wt x Lb)  = Wt (signum x) Lb
  fromInteger x     = Wt (fromInteger x) Lb
  -- Repeat for Kg...
```

Is there any way to specify a generic type for the `Unit` in the Num instance definition? It would be nice to specify something like:

```
instance Num Weight where
  Wt x a + Wt y a = Wt (x + y) a
  -- ...
```

rather than repeating everything with the other constructor.

Comment: Watch out! The kilogram is a unit of mass, not weight. The SI (derived) unit of weight is the Newton, equal to 1 kg m/s^2.

Comment: Are you going to allow adding Kg and Lb together? Otherwise, consider using phantom types to statically guarantee this is not going to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a guard. The following code is an error, as I'm sure you've noticed:

```
instance Num Weight where
    Wt x a + Wt y a = Wt (x + y) a
    -- ...
```

But this is fine:

```
instance Num Weight where
    Wt x a + Wt y b | a == b = Wt (x + y) a
    -- ...
```

Just remember that if someone tries to add kilograms to pounds, your code will error unless you handle that case too.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I've got a `convert` function, so I should be able to do something like: `Wt x a + Wt y b | a == b = Wt (x + y) a otherwise = Wt x a + (convert (Wt y b))` right?

Comment: That seems like it should work. Just don't forget that the `otherwise` clause requires a newline and another vertical bar.